Two-point correlator written as a product of one-point correlators
Let $\phi\left(t\right)$ be
$$\phi\left(t\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger}e^{imt} + \hat{a}e^{-imt} \right).$$
Note:
$\phi\left(t\right)$ solves the differential equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d} t^{2}}\phi\left(t\right) + m^{2}\phi\left(t\right) = 0.$$ This is the differential equation for a simple harmonic oscillator.
Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the normal ordering. My question is, why could the following two point correlator be written as a product of two  one point correlator?
$$\langle 0 |\mathcal{N}\left(\phi_{i_{2}}\left(t\right) \right)\mathcal{N}\left(\phi_{i_{1}}\left(t_{1}\right) \right)| 0 \rangle = \langle 0 |\mathcal{N}\left(\phi_{i_{2}}\left(t\right) \right)| 0 \rangle \langle 0 |\mathcal{N}\left(\phi_{i_{1}}\left(t_{1}\right) \right)| 0 \rangle = 0,$$ where $i_{2} \neq i_{1}$.

Why are there 2 factors of normal ordering here? Are $\phi_{i_{1,2}}$ 2-different sets of fields or just denoting $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$? And do you have a reference for this question?
